# How to set background image for portrait video?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-processing

I have been trying to set background image/CALayer for portrait video so that I can avoid black bars.
I could set image but it shows black background instead of image.

```
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer]
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.with, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = frame;
videoLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
CALayer *backgroundImageLalyer = [CALayer layer]
CALayer *outputLayer = [CALayer layer]
[outputLayer addSublayer:backgroundImageLayer]
[outputLayer addSublayer:videoLayer]

[backgroundLayer setContents:(id)[backgroundImage CGImage]];
backgroundLayer.frame = frame;
[backgroundLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                               videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:outputLayer]
```

Can anyone please suggest me to set background image for portrait videos?

Comment: What are you using to show the video?

Comment: I have created AVMutableComposition which holds video tracks.